# Cannot break out of loop with hasNext

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

Input:

`R Henry Lily`

`R Victor`

`M`

Desired output:

`The members are Henry, Lily, Victor`

My code is:

```
  code = sc.next();
     while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (code.equals("R")) {
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                socialNetwork.registerUser(sc.next());
            }
        else if (code.equals("M"))
            System.out.print("The members are " + socialNetwork.toString());
        code = sc.next()
    }
```

The social network is a modified array class I made in another program. But these parts don't register as I want. Instead of saving it as `[Henry, Lily, Victor]` it saved `[Henry, Lily, R, Victor]`.

Comment: You should generally tag your question with the language you're writing in so it's clear (and people will often follow language tags so they will see your question).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm a newbie here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never quit the inner loop `while(sc.hasNext())` and also even if you would, you never retrieve back the code in the first `while(sc.hasNext())` so only the first code is ever read and all the others will be registered. You probably did not try the `M` option, as using it does not work either and simply register `M`. Another thing that let me believe you haven't tried it is that you output the final array using `socialNetwork.toString()` which will output the memory address of the Object. Here I modified your algorithm to fit your needs :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String code;
String tmpLine;

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    code = sc.next();//retrieve the code
    if (code.equals("R")) {
        tmpLine = sc.nextLine().trim();//read the entire rest of the line
        for(String s : tmpLine.split(" "))// split words by space
            socialNetwork.registerUser(s);
    }    
    else if (code.equals("M"))
    {
        System.out.print("The members are " + String.join(",", socialNetwork));//notice that I use String.join instead of toString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `hasNext()` is used for traverse the list of data and it will check whether there are any more data is present in the list or not. In your case to break out the data inside `hasNext()` loop is quite different. I can suggest that the proper implementation of your execution logic can do your task. You need just few execution changes which will give you your expected output. Please check the below program with few modification of your program.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> socialNetwork=new ArrayList<String>();
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String code=sc.next();
            if(code.equals("R")){
                String checkedCode=sc.next();
                if(!checkedCode.equals("R")){
                    socialNetwork.add(checkedCode);
                }
            }else if(!code.equals("M")){
                String checkedCode=code;
                if(!checkedCode.equals("R")){
                    socialNetwork.add(checkedCode);
                }
            }else{
                //If the code is "M"
                System.out.print("The members are:: ");
                for(int i=0;i<socialNetwork.size();i++){
                System.out.print(socialNetwork.get(i)+" ");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Input -** R Henry Lily R Victor M

**Output -** The members are:: Henry Lily Victor

Hope it will help you.